# Get value from JSON from SharePoint REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, jquery, json

If I use below line, I get output='1'.

```
data.d.results[i].ID;
```

But instead of giving hardcoded **ID**, Is there any way to pass by variable?

I already tried like:

```
var array=["ID","Title"];
data.d.results[i].array[0];
```

Got error: undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID is an object property, so you need to access it like an object property using the square bracket notation instead of dot notation:

```
var array = ["ID", "Title"];

data.d.results[i][array[0]];
```

Using the bracket notation, JS will translate `[array[0]]` into `[ID]` which is equal to `.ID` (notice the dot). Using the dot notation, JS expects `array[0]` to be an object property, which is not.